# Macro to output users logged onto server in cell

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a macro which counts the number of users logged onto a remote server and then output this value into a cell.

Currently, I have used something along the lines of

```
Sub SO()

    Range("A1").Value = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Exec("CMD /S /C powershell -command #InsertCommand#").StdOut.ReadAll

End Sub
```

If I replace #InsertCommand with 'get-date', the date appears in A1, but when replacing which a command to search number of users, it remains blank.

Thanks,

Comment: And this command you mention works when entered manually?

Comment: When entering the command into CMD, it returns a value as expected. The value just will not appear in the cell.

Comment: Can you share the command you want to run? Just wondering if it contains any special characters etc

Comment: '(query user /server:Server1).count'

Are the spaces a problem? Is there another way of doing this?

Comment: I don't think it's the spaces, I'm able to recreate the issue. Even *query* doesn't return any output.